# How to manually load an entity as well as a related entity

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have two entity objects one that holds billing address information(TBLADDRESS) and one that holds my account addresses(TBLMYACCOUNTADDRESS).

At a point in my project i need to load the TBLADDRESS object with the corresponding values from TBLMYACCOUNTADDRESS.  Both of which have a relation to LKSTATE.

My problem is i cannot populate this related entity manually.  Maybe it's not possible?

Here is my script so far, hopefully it will help you better understand exactly what i am trying to accomplish:

```
TBLADDRESS tblBilling = new TBLADDRESS();

TBLMYACCOUNTADDRESS myAccountDefaultAddress = new TBLMYACCOUNTADDRESS();
myAccountDefaultAddress = myAccountAddress.FindAll(delegate(TBLMYACCOUNTADDRESS i) { return i.IS_DEFAULT == true; }).ToList().SingleOrDefault();

tblBilling = new TBLADDRESS();

tblBilling.FIRST_NAME = myAccountDefaultAddress.FIRST_NAME;
tblBilling.LAST_NAME = myAccountDefaultAddress.LAST_NAME;
tblBilling.COMPANY = myAccountDefaultAddress.COMPANY;
tblBilling.ADDRESS_1 = myAccountDefaultAddress.ADDRESS_1;
tblBilling.ADDRESS_2 = myAccountDefaultAddress.ADDRESS_2;
tblBilling.CITY = myAccountDefaultAddress.CITY;
tblBilling.LKSTATE.STATE_ID = myAccountDefaultAddress.LKSTATE.STATE_ID;
tblBilling.POSTAL_CODE = myAccountDefaultAddress.POSTAL_CODE;
tblBilling.PHONE = myAccountDefaultAddress.PHONE;
```

Question is how would i go about populating the tblBilling.LKSTATE.STATE_ID manually.  Currently i get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error message, but something tells me there's more to it than that.

Thanks in Advance,
Billy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

All i need was the instance of the object created before assigning to it.

tblBilling.LKSTATE = new LKSTATE();

Initially i wasn't sure just how to create the instance.  Pretty straightforward.